Install Arch Linux alongside Windows 11 with Arch on a SSD USB medium
How can I install Arch Linux on an external SSD (USB) without affecting the Windows 11 bootloader on my internal drive?
I want to set up a dual-boot system where:

Windows 11 stays intact on the internal NVMe SSD.

Arch Linux is installed on an external USB SSD (1000GB).

The bootloader (GRUB or another) allows easy switching between both OSs.


I'm primarily concerned about:

Avoiding interference with the Windows bootloader (EFI partition).

Properly setting up GRUB to recognize both the external and internal drives.

Ensuring my external USB SSD is recognized correctly during the Arch Linux installation process.


System Setup:

Windows 11 is pre-installed on an internal NVMe SSD.

Target installation for Arch Linux is a 1000GB external SSD (via USB 3).

UEFI is enabled, and I can disable Secure Boot if needed.

No partitions have been set up on the USB SSD yet.


What steps should I follow to ensure the installation goes smoothly without impacting my Windows installation, and what configurations do I need to pay special attention to?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Properly Booting

Install a Boot Manager. For the purposes of this answer I'm going to use rEFInd.
Select the Installation Method. Neither of these will be the easier of the two if you've never done this before. Assuming that at the moment, only Windows 11 is installed, I would choose Installing From Windows.

Download the Binary Zip File from the Getting from SourceForge section and follow the steps at the link provided in Item 2 above. Reboot after completing the steps to ensure that Windows still boots.
Pre-Planning - Optional
I put this here as a functional test, and as a timesaver.  The following steps will install Netboot.xyz, which will prevent the need to create/copy multiple ISO's for tools and OS disks.

After Installing rEFInd, boot to Windows and mount the EFI partition again using mountvol X: /s from an Administrative Command Prompt.  Your EFI Partition is now mounted as X.
Visit the Releases page and download netboot.xyz.efi.  Note: In order to see this the Show All option may need to be used.
From your Command Prompt:

Type X: + Enter
Type cd EFI + Enter
Type dir + Enter. You should see the refind directory created in the Properly Booting Section.
We're going to create another directory with mkdir netboot_xyz + Enter
We now need to copy the netboot.xyz.efi file from Step 2 into the netboot_xyz directory with copy C:\path\to\downloaded\netboot.xyz.efi X:\EFI\netboot_xyz\ + Enter



Pre-Planning - Not Optional

Plug in your USB Drive, ignore or cancel any Windows Prompts to Format etc. and just reboot
If you've followed along with using Netboot.xyz, you should now see that option in the rEFInd menu. This ends the functional test that proves rEFInd is working for more than just Windows.  Boot into Netboot.xyz and choose GParted from the Utilities Menu.  If not using the Optional section, create a GParted Live USB
Boot into GParted and find your USB disk in the GParted screen.
We're now going to create the partitions for Arch on the USB disk before installing Arch. This will allow us to skip Section 1.9 of the Arch Installation Guide. My personal preference here is to use GPT/BSD disk labels in case we lose track of the partitions and device names during the install.
Format the USB disk using the desired filesystem type.  At a minimum, at least 4 partitions are needed:

The EFI partition: FS Type FAT32, with boot flag set.
The /boot partition: FS Type EXT2/3/4 are most common.
The / partition FS Type, Same as /boot
The swap partition FS Type: swap/83


Make sure to fill in the label textbox to match the layout created.
Apply the changes
Install Arch using the Installation Guide.  When mounting the partitions, use the disk labels for easy identification. The drive identifiers (/dev/sd*) should match those from GParted.


Readers may now be asking why I created another EFI partition when there is a perfectly valid EFI partition on the drive with Windows.  There are a few reasons:

We want Windows to continue booting normally, thinking that it is the only OS installed.  Installing Grub in this partition would perform a "hostile takeover" of the Windows Loader and prevent Windows from booting.  See Fixing Windows Boot Problems.
The OP has chosen to install on a removable disk.  If Grub were used as the boot loader, Grub would expect the USB drive be plugged in at every boot, which may not be the OP's desired behavior.
rEFInd will scan multiple EFI partitions across multiple disks.  This allows for each version of Grub to be independently maintained by the OS that installed it.
In the OP's case rEFInd cannot scan an EFI partition if the device with the partition on it is unplugged, which will alleviate Issue 2 discussed above.

Example
I'm providing this here to prove that I've gotten this to work more than once. This is the current disk layout in my Gaming PC:

Disk 1: NVMe - 1TB - Windows 11
Disk 2: Data HDD - 8TB Contains Windows User Profiles, Apps, and Data
Disk 3: Linux - 8TB HDD - Gentoo Linux
Disk 4: Linux - 8TB HDD - Debian Bookworm, Was FreeBSD 12, but I'm thinking  of dropping Gentoo after 20+ years
Disk 5: NVMe - 1TB Steam Storage for games that require High Speed Writes, i.e. CyberPunk etc.


Disk 1's EFI partition contains the rEFInd EFI loader, the Windows Loader, the Gentoo Grub2.efi,and Netboot.xyz.efi
Disk 3 did contain the Grub2.efi for Gentoo until I lost a 10 year plus install, and converted to using UUID's.  The UUID allowed for easier identification of the Windows EFI partition, and therefore knowing I had a boot manager I put Gentoo's Grub2 there the second time.
Disk 4 contains Debian's copy of Grub2.efi and will load Debian, Windows, and my UEFI Firmware (os-prober is on by default).  When installing Debian, I chose "Use entire disk" as I was feeling lazy and in a hurry. This option creates an EFI partition on the disk as this option assumes that the disk being installed to is the only disk in the PC.
Anytime I update Grub in either Gentoo or Debian only those copies are affected (updating Gentoo's Grub2 will not touch Debian, and vice versa).
